# Determining the CLR System Directory

Tags: .net, csc

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5bac5fx(vs.71).aspx) on the C# command-line compiler /lib switch specifies the following:-

> The compiler searches for assembly references that are not fully qualified in the following order:
>
> - Current working directory. This is the directory from which the compiler is invoked.
> - The common language runtime system directory.
> - Directories specified by /lib.
> - Directories specified by the LIB environment variable.

How do you *programmatically* determine where the CLR runtime system directory is located on the system?

Answer (score 3):

native export from mscoree.dll - GetCORSystemDirectory()

Comment: +1 nice one, do you need to have a switch that tries for mscorwks as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You might check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\InstallRoot to find the location of the .Net runtime.

You can access the registry using the [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) classes.

Comment: Unfortunately, unlike Sam Saffron's answer this this does not have version folder.

Comment: But there can be multiple version folders. A simple listing of subdirectories should give you a list of every available version of the framework. All from within the CLR.